# How can I generate crystal report using mysql and php in details

Tags: php

I want to create crystal report from mysql database using PHP.
How to generate a crystal report from a to z?
What tools I need?

Answer (score -1):

If you are creating a report from MySQL you can either use the add command function to create a query to pull the fields you need or you can use the database “wizard” to add the SQL tables you need. There are a number of good resources readily available on You Tube and similar. I hope this helps.